# What are Golang Struct Field Naming Conventions?

Tags: go

I'm trying to learn Go, using Visual Studio Code, and I guess it's using a Go linter. I created this struct to map a JSON object into.

```
type someAPI struct {
    ApiEndpoint string   `json:"apiEndpoint"`
    ApiVersion  string   `json:"apiVersion"`
    ...
}
```

And I get these warnings...

> struct field ApiEndpoint should be APIEndpoint
>
> struct field ApiVersion should be APIVersion

I did some Googling and I can not find any requirements for struct field names regarding this. The most I've found is that if you want to make a field public you have to capitalize it.

So why is this linter warning me about these names?

I did some testing by changing `Api` to `Abc` and the linter didn't warn me to change it to "ABC". So I have to assume it's checking for names that start with "Api".

What are Go conventions for field names? Or in other words, are there other conventions I should know about?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For most cases the naming convention in Go is just to use camel case and start with upper case if it's a public field and lower case if it's not. But in words that are acronyms like API or URL they are written in full upper case eg. `func ProxyURL(fixedURL *url.URL)` on the [http package](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyURL).

**EDIT:** I searched for a little bit more and there are guidelines for acronyms on the [Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments). It talks about acronyms in the [Initialisms](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#initialisms) section:

> Words in names that are initialisms or acronyms (e.g. "URL" or "NATO")
>   have a consistent case. For example, "URL" should appear as "URL" or
>   "url" (as in "urlPony", or "URLPony"), never as "Url". As an example:
>   ServeHTTP not ServeHttp. For identifiers with multiple initialized
>   "words", use for example "xmlHTTPRequest" or "XMLHTTPRequest".
>
> This rule also applies to "ID" when it is short for "identifier", so
>   write "appID" instead of "appId".

So the rule for acronyms is that they should have constant case. In your case because they have to start with uppercase "A" you should write them as "API".

Also this is just my personal opinion and I know that the code in the example might not be the exact code you are using but if it is, I think it's a bad practice to include the struct name on the field names. You are doing `api.APIField` but `api.Field` is easier to read and if you know the object is an API then there is not doubt that the Field belongs to an API.

Comment: So there's a list of uppercase enforced acronyms? Do you know of any documentation that suggests using uppercase for acronyms? I guess I'm wondering if this is just something I'm seeing because of the linter VSC is using, or would something like fmt warn me as well?

Comment: I don't know of any docs that suggest doing it that way. On the go blog they wrote about using camel case but it doesn't say anything about the acronyms. And `gofmt` https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/ doesn't enforce naming conventions for acronyms, so I guess it's just the way they implemented it in VSC, but it is the way the standard library is written so if you want to stick to a standard that is probably the one you should use.

Comment: @Jerinaw I found the docs for acronyms naming. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Jerinaw Your IDE is likely using golint, which defines [this list](https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/lint.go#L749) of "known initialisms" that it complains about if they aren't constant-case.

Comment: What if I have a cascade of multiple acronyms? In Java that's why I use names like `HttpHttpsSwitcher`, but according to this guideline it would be `HTTPHTTPSSwitcher` (or `httphttpsSwitcher` for reduced visibility) which is painful to read. Underscores?

Comment: @NotX I agree that it is painful to read in this but that's the standard so if you want to follow it that's the way to go. If you think readability is more important than sticking with the standard I would definitely go the Java way and not use underscores. Underscores are really not used in go and the Java way still complies with the camel case standard just not with the acronym part so it's not that bad.
A comment on your example above: if the field is not exported then it would be `httpHTTPSwitcher` if you follow the rule.

Comment: what about the filename ?

Answer (score 4):

Like mentioned here in your question and in @topo's answer, the convention for variable an function naming is Camel Case (mixed caps). If the name starts with an upper case letter the variable/function can be exported.

Packages are always lower case.

Interfaces should end with `-er`

You can read more in the [effective go naming session](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names)

Golint on the other hand, goes beyond Go convention for naming. There are a few rules for words and in your case you are hitting one of the rules. You can see the full list here: https://github.com/golang/lint/blob/master/lint.go#L751